# Emailing myself the content of Sheets returns #ERROR! for GoogleFinance functions with AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to create a spreadsheet that keeps track of stock prices. this works so far with =GoogleFinance and =YahooFinance. But when it comes to emailing myself the list via a time trigger, i get the "#ERROR!"  message in the cells instead of the content of =GoogleFinance.
It seems that those functions =GoogleFinance don't retrieve the data when the spreadsheet is not open in a browser tab. If i have the spreadsheet in the browser open, emailing the data works for an hour or so.

coding is not my trade, so i would be very thankful for any help.

```
var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/....';
var SHEET_NAME = 'sheet';

function myFunction() {
  
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  template.data = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL)
    .getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var body = template.evaluate().getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "@gmail.com",
    subject: "test",
    htmlBody: body
  })
}
```

here is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sometimes, the content of that email for some cells are #NAME? or #ERROR! and i am not sure what is going wrong. Refreshing that spreadsheet in the browser mostly works just fine.

Comment: Can you share a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I have been running some tests and it seems like even when logged out of my account, the trigger continues and the data is sent by email correctly. Can you confirm if its a Gmail or Workspace account?

Comment: Thank you for taking time to do some testing. I have added the code.
I am using a free gmail account and i am sending the mail also to myself.
The trigger event works fine, i can set it to send every 10 min and i get the mails, only the content of the cells of the =GoogleFinance is not available.

Comment: Mine has been running all weekend and I am not getting any #ERROR values. Maybe you could share a sample sheet with code included on which this reproduces?

Comment: I am finding that the YAHOO FINANCE formula fail sometimes, but not always. On the otherhand the GOOGLEFINANCE ones always work, is this the case for you too?

Comment: true, yahoofinance does not fail everytime, but quite often. googlefinance on the other hand has empty cells every couple days. the code in the top seems to work better than the one i had before. so i guess i only use yahoo for some data and pull the rest from google. thanks for sticking with me, iansedano.